# Why is there (void*) in front of malloc?

Tags: c++, function

```
void* buffer = (void*)malloc(100);
```

By prefixing the malloc() function with (void*), what is being achieved, are we overriding the return type?

Comment: It means that the author doesn't know that `malloc` returns a pointer of type `void*`

Comment: It's a *cast*, not a prefix, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of the call to `malloc` is being explicitly cast to a `void` pointer. This is sort of redundant, as it already returns a `void*`, but is <strike>probably</strike> possibly present to clarify the developer's intention (or he just screwed up).

Comment: "is probably present to clarify the developer's intention" If that is so then it's a big misthink on the part of the author. Casts have the effect of abandoning the type system. Sane programmers try as hard as they can never to use casts. Adding spurious needless casts is crass beyond belief.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan True, good point. I always try to give the benefit of the doubt, but just edited my response nonetheless.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing is achieved since malloc already returns a void pointer. This is equivalent to:

```
void* buffer = malloc(100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. But what does that prefix do then?

Comment: It does nothing, you can remove it and the code is equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, it does nothing. However, since C++ is much more strict than C regarding type safety, you generally need to cast the return of `malloc`:

```
void* x = malloc(100);       //OK in C/C++
int*  y = malloc(100);       //OK in C, error in C++
int*  z = (int*)malloc(100); //OK in C/C++, not recommended for C
```

However, since you use C++, I can't not tell you that you should use `new` instead.